# Jar not starting on double click, but starts from command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm using IntelliJ to create JAR file, and **it executes normally when run from command line, but on double clicking it, nothing happens**. The JAR I export from eclipse work normally, and since I'm a beginner using IntelliJ my guess is that I am doing something wrong.

I'm exporting the JAR in this way:

```
Project structure -> jar -> from modules and dependencies then use this 
    configuration to build.
```

Comment: What do you mean by double clicking the jar? A jar file is not an executable, it is just a box with compiled code.

Comment: Yes, but eclipse can export runnable jars, that you can click and it works the same as having an exe file

Comment: How do you start it from the command line?

Comment: try to install JRE and it will work :) i faced the same problem

Comment: You are on Windows? Does the file have a `.jar` extension?

Comment: Can you provide listing what is the total directory output with Eclipse vs IntelliJ? Also can you extract `MANIFEST.MF` from each jar via `jar xf file.jar` and provide content of each?

Comment: contents of the MANIFEST.MF files are the same, there is no visible difference between jars generated using IntelliJ and Eclipse, the manifests match, but the jars from eclipse run on double click and the ones from intellij don't.

Comment: Another silly question - how about file size? next from there I would look at your file associations. - i.e. what happens on default double click with jar files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why everyone is playing dumb about self executing jars.
Just add a MANIFEST.MF file and specify the fully qualified main class as Main-Class: my.package.MyClass

Also, make sure your executable type for .jar file type is Java

Once you do this you can just double click the jar to execute it.

Comment: the jar already has this file with the folowing contents:`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: entry.Main`, which is why I don't understand why it's not executing.

Comment: It's probably because you need to associate the jar type with Java.

Comment: they work fine if they have been exported by eclipse, they don't work only if exported by IntelliJ

Comment: Open the two jars (using a zip file viewer like Winzip) and see what the difference is.

Comment: Make sure the Manifest.mf is in the directory meta-inf\. (meta-inf\ itself is at the root level)

Comment: I can confirm it's at that location. the only difference in jars seems to be that intellij seems to add empty nameless folders inside every folder. deleting them changes nothing.

Comment: Java doesn't know which IDE created your jar. There must be something different between the two jars. In the manifest please check spelling, case difference, white space, ':' position. Also check the actual directory structure between the two. The empty folders should not matter, but remove them just to make everything equal

Answer (score 0):

Intellij will not execute a JAR for you. Remember JAR is a container, Is the same as if you were asking to execute a ZIP file.

What I am sure you want is to execute a class inside your jar file. Which would be the class which has the:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

You have two options:

1) execute the jar from command Line

2) right click on the "main" word I wrote above and then press RUN.. You will see a small green arrow (play button). That is the only way of running a class inside Intellij.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't need IntelliJ to execute a jar for me, I'd like to know how I can create executable jars.

Comment: Oh ok. well, are you using maven or similar?.. If not, you can see how to build and create your own jar in this link. Hope it helps :) blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact

Comment: I don't use maven, my jar exports fine and works from command line, but unline the ones produced by eclipse it does not start on double click.

Comment: What happens when you double click? does it opens and tries to extract files? Did you create the jar file using the instructions from the link i gave you?

Comment: when I double click absolutely nothing happens, I used the link you gave me to create the jar the first time arround.

Answer (score 0):

If your JAR starts from the command line using `jar -jar <file>`, that's as executable as a JAR file gets (in other words, metadata specifies where the main class is). You can if you want use the OS provided tools to specify that when you double click on a .jar file, it should execute `java -jar <file>`, but that's beyond the scope of JAR files. If you're running Windows for example, you should be able to achieve this by following the procedure outlined [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320036). Again, this is OS specific and may even be specific to which version you're running, and is essentially just a fancy wrapper around the double-click event to execute the `java -jar` command.

Comment: How does eclipse manage to do it? the same project exported using eclipse works when double clicked...

Comment: It's pretty easy for any given piece of software to specifically override what double click does. All it needs to do is to run `java -jar <file>` silently in the background. I took it from the way you formulated your question that you wanted double click to work anywhere, not just in IntelliJ. The only way I know of that you could use in IntelliJ is to define an external tool (which won't work as a double click as far as I know, but it'll be in the right-click menu of the file instead).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the x-flag is set for the jar.

```
java -jar xyz.jar
```

does not need that, but double click need it:

```
ls -l xyz.jar
chmod 755 xyz.jar
```